# How to resolve job_1634335400729_0001 failed with state FAILED due to: Application application_1634335400729_0001 failed 2 times error on hadoop

Tags: hadoop, mahout

whenever I try to splitData using

mahout splitDataset --input /mini_datasets1/wimmer-mini_obesity_data2.csv --output mini_datasets1/wimmer-mini_obesity_data2split --trainingPercentage 0.7 --probePercentage 0.3

on hadoop I get the error below

Job job_1634335400729_0001 failed with state FAILED due to: Application application_1634335400729_0001 failed 2 times due to AM Container for appattempt_1634335400729_0001_000002 exited with  exitCode: 1
Failing this attempt.Diagnostics: [2021-10-15 18:05:06.026]Exception from container-launch.
Container id: container_1634335400729_0001_02_000001
Exit code: 1

pls does anyone know how to resolve the error?? I already configured yarn-site.xml

Comment: You need to look at the YARN UI / application logs for the actual failure cause

Comment: Please I am new to Hadoop these are the errors

[main] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster: MAX_APP_ATTEMPTS is null
FATAL [main] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster: Error starting MRAppMaster
java.io.IOException: MAX_APP_ATTEMPTS is null
 at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster.validateInputParam(MRAppMaster.java:1332)
 at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster.main(MRAppMaster.java:1358)
INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.util.ExitUtil: Exiting with status 1: java.io.IOException: MAX_APP_ATTEMPTS is null

Comment: I have tried editing my yarn-site.xml severally but I still get the same error, I also realized I keep getting 

JAR does not exist or is not a normal file  when ever I put in this command 
hadoop jar share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples-3.3.0.jar grep input output 'dfs[a-z.]+'
 The examples file is in the supposed location

Comment: Unclear what folder you're running that command from

Comment: From hadoop home, I also tried running the command in the location of the jar file and I still got the same error.

Comment: I've not really used hadoop since version 2.7. Maybe they removed the examples JAR in some higher version

Comment: Thank you for your time I am guessing if I cant run that jar file I will not be able to do any MapReduce task

Comment: You dont need the example JAR to run mapreduce. Mahout itself still uses Hadoop 2.10 in the source code, by the way